# Word for substance being diluted

Tags: terminology

The liquid we use to dilute is the diluent, what is the substance that is being diluted called? I considered "dilutant" but it seems ambiguous. I can't seem to find a common term in literature either.

A possible analogy is solute and solvent. You'd think there'd be a counterpart for diluent too.

Comment: I'd go with stock solution, probably.

Comment: Maybe *diluate*?

Comment: I like *diluand* ☺

Comment: If you think about it, both liquids are being diluted, no? So maybe they are both diluents...